# Access a field on an extended class that does not exist on the base, which the type parameter is that of the base

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Forgive me but I'm new to C# and cannot find an answer to this anywhere... Given the four class examples below; How would I *refine* the type of `metadata` from `AssetMetadata` to `LegMetadata`?

```
public abstract class AssetMetadata : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string name;
}

public class LegMetadata : AssetMetadata
{
    public float thickness;
}    

public abstract class AssetController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AssetMetadata metadata;
}

public class LegController : AssetController
{
    private void Start()
    {
        metadata = GetComponent<AssetMetadata> ();
        Debug.Log (metadata.thickness);
    }
}
```

The reason I ask this if in the below `LegController` script `metadata.thickness` is not a valid field because it does not exist on the abstract class it inherits from. I know I could do something like...

```
public class LegController : AssetController
{
    private LegMetadata _metadata;

    private void Start()
    {
        _metadata = GetComponent<LegMetadata>();
        // ... this feels wrong
    }
}
```

or...

```
public class LegController : AssetController
{
    private void Start()
    {
        metadata = GetComponent<AssetMetadata> ();
        Debug.Log (((LegMetadata)metadata).thickness);
        // ... still looking bad
    }
}
```

There's got to be a better way to handle this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: var specificObject = generalObject as SpecificType; then check if null, or using the new syntax if (generalObject is SpecificType specificObject)

Comment: Why can't you move `float thickness` to `AssetMetadata` and then override/inherit it from there?

Comment: an AssetMetadata is not a LegMetadata, but a LegMetadata is an AssetMetadata

Comment: @JustinJmnz contrived and simplified example. The reason would be that other AssetMetadata aren't concerned about thickness.

Comment: @Lestat Thanks but that is understood.

Comment: @DannyVarod thanks but `var` is method scoped and I feel like I shouldn't have to do this conversion every method call.

Comment: What about calling  `_metadata = GetComponent<LegMetadata>();` feels wrong? If you really need it, then what's stopping you from calling it. You get all the benefits from it's inherited class, but the functionality of `LegMetadata`

Comment: @JustinJmnz I'm new to C# and I just figured there'd be a more idiomatic approach to this. Doing it this way means my class has an extraneous field that is never used after initialization.

Comment: Yeah, I think all your reasonable options are on the table.  1) You request the specific type you want, or 2) You request the base type, knowing you will get the derived type, or 3) you request the base type and conditionally cast it to the derived type.  Your question deals with 1 and 2 just fine, and @DannyVarod 's response deals with 3.  I can't think of why one of these options wouldn't be appropriate, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: My thinking there's a better way probably comes from my unfamiliarity with the language syntax. Thank you all!

Comment: Your classes already have their inherited type once you initialize them. If you are only going to use `.thickness` from `LegMetadata` then why would you inherit from anything in the first place? One point of inheritance is to take out common parts so you don't have to re-write them over and over.

Comment: Of course, there's other approaches, like having virtual methods/properties in the base that conditionally return this data (you could even make it nullable), or reflection, where you get the type as an examinable object, and operate on it like that (and in that approach you could do switch statements or even dictionary lookups).  So...there *are* other approaches, but they kind of boil down to tackling one of the same 3 scenarios.

Comment: @JustinJmnz yes I know that, there's obviously going to be other things on `AssetMetadata` that are common to things other than just `LegMetadata`. I want to be able to give a base type to the script in the unity editor to easy the development process for people making model assets.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @KyleRichardson - Sorry, a thought just occurred to me because of "idiomatic".  A programming idiom that is popular in C# is "favor composition over inheritance".  Arguable, but MS C# folks generally agree with it.  There's really nothing in your (simplified) example to indicate composition would help *at all*, but C# does lend itself nicely to composition.  Just...a very high level thought for your consideration.  I suspect useless for this scenario, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work in your particular example, because it's not a 100% clear what you're trying to achieve, but you could make the abstract `Controller` into a generic class providing the type of metadata with the type parameter:

```
public abstract class AssetMetadata : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string name;
}

public class LegMetadata : AssetMetadata
{
    public float thickness;
}

public abstract class Controller<TMetadata> : MonoBehaviour where TMetadata : AssetMetadata
{
    public TMetadata metadata;
}

public class LegController : Controller<LegMetadata>
{
    private void Start()
    {
        metadata = GetComponent<LegMetadata>();
        Debug.Log(metadata.thickness);
    }
}
```

With this approach you can create specific controllers for specific metadata types, although you'd still need to cast if you're using `GetComponent` with a type that derives from the type of the controller's type parameter.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be a better way.